# Is there a way to check if a manifest in a Docker registry is multi-arch or not?

Tags: docker, cpu-architecture, docker-registry

When you pull a multi-arch manifest from a Docker registry, it automatically picks an individual image that matches your computer's architecture and pulls that one instead (if possible); from the client's side, this appears identical to pulling a single-arch image manifest. Is there a way to determine whether the manifest is single-arch or multi-arch from the client's side, e.g. by querying an API endpoint?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are lots of tools for this. Built into docker is:

```
$ docker buildx imagetools inspect busybox
Name:      docker.io/library/busybox:latest
MediaType: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json
Digest:    sha256:7b3ccabffc97de872a30dfd234fd972a66d247c8cfc69b0550f276481852627c
...
```

You're looking for the media type. `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json` and `application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json` are multi-platform manifests with a list of supported platforms.

Outside of docker, there's also crane from Google, skopeo from RedHat, and regclient/regctl from myself. An example of a shell script to give a true/false using regctl can be done with the formatted output:

```
$ regctl manifest get busybox --format '{{ .IsList }}'
true

$ regctl manifest get busybox --platform local --format '{{ .IsList }}'
false
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only `MediaType` value, you can run:

```bash
$ docker buildx imagetools inspect --format '{{json .Manifest.MediaType}}' busybox
"application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json"
```